# "Local variable referenced before assignment" error while declaring variable same as the imported class

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
local variable 'Document' referenced before assignment
```

I keep on getting this variable unbound error but i do not seem to understand why.

Importing it seems fine. I am using django 1-10

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from forms import DocumentForm
from models import Document

def SaveDocument(request):
    saved = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        #Get the posted form
        MyDocumentForm = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if MyDocumentForm.is_valid():
            print 'It enters here'
            Document = Document()
            Document.name = MyDocumentForm.cleaned_data["name"]
            Document.document = MyDocumentForm.cleaned_data["document"]
            Document.save()
            saved = True
        else:
            print 'Fails'
    else:
        MyDocumentForm = DocumentForm()

    return render(request, 'saved.html', locals())
```

Comment: `Document = Document()`... You just overwrote the import. Don't make your variables uppercase, anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you just redefine Document inside SaveDocument() function.
Just rename local variable to `document` instead of `Document`:

```
document = Document()
```

Answer (score 2):

When Python parses the body of a function definition and encounters an assignment such as

```
foo = ...
```

Python interprets `foo` as a local variable by default.

Hence, when you mentioned:

```
Document = Document()
```

The `Document` you imported was no longer accessible within your `SaveDocument()` function. In order to make this work, change it to:

```
document = Document()
```

and use the referrence of `document` in rest of your code.

You may verify this via telling Python to use the `global` reference of `Document` *(which will let you execute your current code)* as:

```
global Document 
Document = Document()  
# NOTE: Do not use this in actual code. It is bad practice to 
# override the imported modules, class, function with the variable names
```

---

As per the Python's [The `global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) document:

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.